# Under New Management - How do I get the One with the Shadows achievement?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

I've completed all the side quests and main quests for the guild but still haven't received the achievement for returning the thieves guild to its former glory.

When I try to speak to Brynjolf he just keeps saying "sorry lad I've got important things to do"

Any ideas how I can get this achievement?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46741/becoming-thieves-guild-guildmaster-am-i-bugged -- This might be it? I ended up using the console cheat :-/

Comment: Have you done odd jobs from Vex & Delvin then the 5 special jobs from Delvin?  The trophy should pop after the 5 special jobs are completed.

Comment: Still stuck with this, I've tried loads of stuff. I've done the 5 side quests: Imitation Amnesty, Summerset Shadows, Silver Lining and The Dainty Sload. But no achievement appears just keep getting the same message from Brynjolf. I can't use console as I'm on an xbox.

Comment: it seems to be a bug on the xbox with the latest patch release. If you completed all the thieves guild quests/special jobs etc BEFORE you finish darkness returns then that Brynjolf guy just says he's busy all the time, I haven't found a fix for this yet & I'm lvl 64...no way am i starting again!
So if you kept the skeleton key for easy lockpicking this could be your problem If I delete the patch the game wont run

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Becoming Thieves Guild Guildmaster, am I bugged?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46741/4797)

Answer (score 3):

> In order to restore the Thieves' Guild to its former glory and assume the title of Guildmaster, you must perform 4 'special jobs' across four major Holds of Skyrim: Whiterun, Markarth, Windhelm, and Solitude.
>   
> In order to get a special job, you must first complete 5 smaller jobs in that hold. To get a job, talk to Delvin Mallory or Vex. The small job targets are randomized across the major holds and a tally of the small jobs is not visible to the player.
>   
> Jobs can be accepted and quit at will so if you have done all the jobs in a perticular hold select to quit the current job and ask for a new one (It can be the same style of job) untill you get the hold you need.
>   After completing 5 jobs in a particular Hold, Delvin Mallory will offer a Special Job in order to increase the Thieves' Guild influence in that Hold.
>   
> Once you have completed all four Special Jobs, it will start the 'Under New Management' quest. From here you can talk to Brynjolf to officially assume the title of Guildmaster but you will need to retrive you Thieves Guild armour so Do not sell it.

All of the above info and much more detailed information can be found at [trueachievements.com](http://www.trueachievements.com/achievement.aspx?achievementid=157044&showguides=1)

Comment: I don't think that it is 5 quests for each hold. I know that is what the Elder Scrolls Wiki says, but I did the special quest after 4 radiant quests in all of the holds

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you must complete all of Vex's and Delvin's side quest which are described as extra jobs by the Guild NPCs You must complete all the quest successfully without getting caught in the quests where you must pickpocket or steal something. Once this is done you talk to Brynjolf

Comment: You can never complete all these quests, new ones will be generated randomly.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug. If you're playing on the PC, installing the **[Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19)** should fix that issue.

Its related fix is:

> Brynjolf will no longer dismiss the player's conversation indicating that he's busy after the Thieves Guild questline

<sup>[Full Unofficial Skyrim Patch changelog](http://www.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Patch%20Version%20History.html)</sup>