# Why am I no longer recognized as Guild Master of the Thieves Guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed the main quest, all of the city quests, all of the special quests, I have all of the venders.  I was given access to the guild master chest ect.  I have the guild master gear, and I even got the dialog changes for becoming the guild master.

Some time during my game play, this changed?

I went back to the Guild Hall and I had to pay to become a member again.  I no longer get the dialog changes from all the NPCs for being the guild master.  I still have access to the chests, but for the stones of Barenziah quest, the full member of the thieves guild requirement is no longer checked. I still have access to the venders that sell stolen things for you.

I don't really understand why I'm no longer recognized as the Guild Leader. D: Help!

Comment: Maybe you assaulted someone from the thieves guild and got expelled. There should be a quest to let you back into the guild if that is the case, go through all your uncompleted quests and see if it is there, if it is, complete the quest to get back into the guild.

Comment: @Kevin megan mentioned that she had to pay to become a member again, that *was* the [quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reparations) to let you get back into the guild.  If she's still not considered guild master, it might be a glitch.

Comment: @spartacus Oops didn't see that part

Comment: Yep, you're officially glitched by the sounds of it. I'd go through the wiki pages to see if it's a known glitch and if it is, how in the name of Hades you fix it.

Comment: This is very similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46741/becoming-thieves-guild-guildmaster-am-i-bugged

Answer (score 1):

You may have robbed, assaulted, or murdered a protected person or member. Also any crimes against the guild and you have to pay your guild bounty.

Answer (score -4):

If you get kicked out you have to do about 10-15 of the small jobs to be guild master again

I hope this helped

Edit: you do this after the quest where you have to pay

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?  It doesn't fit with the [Reparations](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Reparations) quest that you are given if you are dismissed from the guild.

Comment: No you do this after that quest I have also tested it on four different files