# Why is Brynjolf guildmaster, not me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed all the quests required to become guild master and was told that I would be guild master after I returned the key. But now Brynjolf is wearing the master armour and he is always too busy to talk.

So why is Brynjolf guildmaster not me?

Comment: "*I completed all the quests required to become guild master... yet Brynjolf ... is always too busy to talk*" This is probably a bug. Solutions have been suggested in answers to this question: [Becoming Thieves Guild Guildmaster, am I bugged?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46741/4797)

Comment: Brynjolf doesn't tell you that you'll be guildmaster after the key. He tells you you'll be guildmaster after the guild gets back on it's feet. Which is why you then have to restore the guild to it's former honours

Answer (score 3):

You have to do radiant quests with Delvin and Vex until you are asked to do a reputation question for the major holds. Once you complete all of the reputation quests you can then move on to the final quest and be made Guild Master.

For more information on the reputation quests you can find a list of them, and all other thieves guild related quests, here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)