# Becoming Guildmaster glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've upgraded the guild so I have all the fences around the ragged flagon, I've done all the quests in my quest log that relates to the guild. When I came back from returning the Skeleton Key (nothing glitchy about that quest, it showed up as completed and everything) I was expecting for Brynjolf to walk up to me when I got back and ask me about the key and say "Why don't you become guild master?" or something but he had disappeared form the guild completely and I couldn't find him anywhere. And if I spawn him in he's wearing the guild master's armor and the only dialogue option I had was "How is the Guild doing ?" he would reply about how its better with Mercer gone and the guild is in such a prosperous state and he said he was proud of the guild and of the guild master. - WHAT? no other dialogue options appear for me and I'm so confused and If I use the -setstage TGleadership 0- console command nothing happens! Karliah is in the Nightingale Sanctuary, just chilling out, completely normal BTW. Please help.

Something similar happened on the Dark BH quest HAIL SITHIS! where the final dramatic Emperor's cutscene wouldn't trigger and no console commands could fix it so I can never, ever finish the Dark BH quest line...

Comment: Did you complete all the city thieving quests from Vex and that other dude?

Comment: @n_palum Yes, I did

Comment: This looks like it is not a duplicate of [Becoming Thieves Guild Guildmaster, am I bugged?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46741/108003), because Brynjolf says a different line, and because the asker already tried the solution in the answer to that question, but it didn't work.

Comment: You tried the setstage command from the question I linked. Did you try killing Sapphire?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset your game to before you returned the Key. Also, the fact that you have gotten the guild built up and have all the fences already, yet haven't become Guildmaster yet, is not normal... so it's possible that the game believes that you have already become Guildmaster.